# Start up items doesent load properly

Tags: windows, boot, usb, event-viewer

Here are my system specs; all new components:

- Ryzen 5600x
- 2x8gb G.Skill Trident Neo Z 3600 16/19/19/39
- X570 MSI Tomahawk Wi-Fi (latest BIOS)
- Corsair Force Series MP600 Gen. 4
- MSI Gaming GeForce RTX 3080 Gaming X Trio or GeForce GTX 1030
- PSU Antec 1300w HCP
- Windows 10 H20 version/tried 1909 same problem

Every second or third PC power on I get problem entering a desktop screen. I have to wait around 20 seconds and looking to a log in window with my PC name to get to the desktop screen its like a Windows Explorer is not responding.

I tried to restart Windows Explorer, it doesent help all programs (which are set to auto boot) are not loading the whole right side by the watch and network position, cursor (mouse) is spinning all the time so I cannot press start menu too. All I can do is hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>alt</kbd>/<kbd>delete</kbd> or restart or shut down.

All processes in task manager are normal CPU/GPU/RAM/SSD.

I can assume that programs are loaded but no showing because I have Argus Monitor installed and all fans are set up to 30% with boot so Argus Monitor is working properly since there is no noise from fans like in default BIOS set up for the fans. So every time I get into problematic state I have to restart PC and then all is good.

I want to fix this problem.

Also i have checked the event viewer and i have a found a several errors:

```
Critical 10110 and 10110 user mode driver problem
App model runtime 65/31
DistributeCOM
VSS (after this error appear i did disable shadow copies/back up aut win)
perflib
```

I did a Google search for critical 10110 and 10110 error and found that this error is related to USB connected devices so I applied a few potential solutions.

- Deleted all greyed out devices manager profiles under (show hidden devices) — under power plan disable USB selected suspend -under device manager/universal serial bus controllers all 3 USB devices all set to disable allow to computer to turn off this device I have 3 USB devices connected.

  - Apex 7 TKL Pro Keyboard
  - Razer DeathAdder v2 PRO WI FI
  - V2 Pro Logitech G Pro Headphones (DAC variant)

After changing this setting for USB devices I had no problems for a week. But now its happening again.

List of programs which are set up to start in Windows:

- Argus monitor
- MSI Dragon Center
- LG Hub
- Razer Synapse 3
- SteelSeries Engine 3 Core
- MSI Afterburner
- ParkControl
- Nvidia Experience
- Kaspersky Total Security (Note: The problem appeared even before A.V.)

Things I tried also:

- All autoboot program disable to not start with windows no go.
- MSI bios set to default no go/flash to newer version no go.
- XMP on/of or profile 1/2 no go.
- Eject CMOS battery 20min waiting no go.
- MemTest86 passed
- Rolled back to Windows 1909 and 2004 no go.
- Several clean install doesn’t help.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Your title is misleading. Slow or erratic boot does not equate with Explorer issues.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik If you have a better title, please edit. I worded the title because the original title was simply “Need advanced assistance” and I honestly found — and still find — the massive details here very hard to understand.

Comment: Yes massive details because is a massive problem

Comment: I edited title and question about start up items,now you can make a active thread